# Некорректный вывод

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Всем привет!
Мне нужно, чтобы в select выводились полученные данные из БД
Для этого имеется в index.php такой код:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

     load_data();

     function load_data(query)
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"fetch.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('.result').html(data);
       }
      });
     }
     $('#date_groups').keyup(function(){
      var search = $(this).val();
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Вот сам fetch.php

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "1", "1", "1");
$output = '';

$query = "SELECT `group` FROM `21.02.18` ORDER BY `group`";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    //$output .= '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td></tr>';
    //$output .= '<option data-tokens="'.$row["group"].'">'.$row["group"].'</option>';
    //$output .= '<option data-tokens="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
    $output .= $row[0];
}
echo $output;

?>
```

в select вывожу так:

```
<option class="result"></option>
```

Но беда в том, что выводит одной длинной строкой.
А мне нужно как обычный выпадающий список, несколько строк, а не одной.
Код нашёл где-то в интернете, если что :)

Comment: Добрый вечер. Но у Вас же есть закомментированный, правильный код. Чем он Вас не устраивает?

Comment: он также выводит одной строкой

Comment: Проблема была решена с помощью slo_nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так

```
$output = '';

while(***){
  $output .= '<option data-tokens="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
}
echo $output;
```

На странице создайте select

```
<select id="result" name="result"></select>
```

В js коде просто вставляйте в этот список то, что пришло с сервера.

```
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
```